# socket.io error on client side

Tags: node.js, sockets

I spend a few days on the problem.I am trying to build a page with `socket.io`.
I am a beginer of `node.js & socket.io`. I read the `socket.io` doc, and build the page step by step.
And then i got a error, `Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined`

But i can get the js content from `http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js`

I use `var socket = io.connect('http://localhost')` or use `var socket = io()` on client side. Neither is ok.What show i do?

Here is my code in server side:

```
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = 3000;
http.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
})
```

In client side:

```
var socket = io();
socket.on('news', function(data){
    console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: PLease share your code

Comment: sorry, because of GFW .i use ipad to post this ,is not easy to post my code

Comment: server side  var app = express();var http = require('http').Server(app);var io = require('socket.io')(http);var port = 3000;http.listen(port, function(){console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);})

Comment: client side  var socket = io();socket.on('news', function(data){console.log(data);})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client side, you should use the server.io client

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
```

You can run

```
npm i socket.io-client
```

to install the dependency or alternatively you can serve the file socket.io.js found in the dist folder provided from https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

*Not tested*
In your pug template, you can do in head or body,

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
    head
    script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js").
    //Your logic here
```

Comment: I use pug for view ,howshould i add this?

Comment: thanks，i finally found a error in the pug file i forget to write src= in script